# how to get first element from a Tupled List

Tags: c#, string, list, tuples

I have a list i.e.

```
var d = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
```

used in following code as under:

```
var d = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                d.Add(Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, document)));
            }


            System.IO.StreamWriter fileW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\write_research_fields_temp.txt");

            foreach (var item in d.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2))
            {
                fileW.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Item2, item.Item1);

            }
```

I want to store first element (only string value not double value) of sorted (descending) List in a string i.e. `string top_value`

Any suggestion are highly appreciated.
Thanks

---

```
 var dd = new List<Tuple<string, double, string>>();

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                dd.Add(Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, document), document));
            }

            var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

            if (top_value != null)
            { 
                // look up record using top_value.Item3, and then store top_value.Item1
                var abstrct = top_value.Item3.ToString();
                var r_field = top_value.Item1.ToString();

                write_To_Database(abstrct, r_field);
            }
```

This is insertion method to insert data into database.

```
static void write_To_Database(string document, string research_field)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHIZER;Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True;");

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
                query.CommandText = "select id from sub_aminer_paper where pid between 1 and 500 and DATALENGTH(p_abstract) != 0 and p_abstract = " + document;

                SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();


                reader.Read();
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                //reader.Close();

                query.Parameters.Add("@research_field", SqlDbType.Text);
                query.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);

                query.CommandText = "insert into sub_aminer_paper (research_area) values(@research_field) where id = @id";
                query.ExecuteNonQuery();


                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");

            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you've got a *list* here, so there will be multiple strings. Which do you want? Or are you looking for a `List<string>`?

Comment: I have sorted the list descending on basis of double value in Tuple but now I need the first (i.e. highest double value) element of the List but only string with out that highest double value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a little LINQ to sort the collection and grab the desired result.

This orders by your numerical value (largest on top), then grabs the first string value paired with it:

```
string top_value = d.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2)
                    .Select(x => x.Item1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In your existing code, there's no need to iterate through all the results just to get the first, so you could basically do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in d.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2))
{
    string top_value = item.Item1;
    ... // do stuff
    break;
}
```

But that'd be a little silly, so you could eliminate the loop:

```
var orderedItems = d.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2);
var largestItem = d.FirstOrDefault();  // covers the case where the list is empty

string top_value = largestItem != null ? largestItem.Item1 : null;
```

Personally I prefer LINQ, but YMMV. :)

---

As for storing it in the database, it looks like you lose the value of `document` when you create the Tuple. I'd just change the Tuple to store the document too, and modify the LINQ statement slightly:

```
var d = new List<Tuple<string, double, string>>();

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    d.Add(Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, document), document));
}

var top_value = d.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

if (top_value != null)
{
    // look up record using top_value.Item3, and then store top_value.Item1
}
```

Comment: Its appreciable @Grant but now I have to write this string into database.......and I have to match the database row with document in the tuple then insert this string against that document

Comment: "how to store value in sql server table after comparing with local string value c#"
you can concern my this question for better understandng

Comment: No no dear @Grant, if you can able to see the code posted in that question. there is a variable "string document", so i have to match this string with the entry in database, so where there is a match found, i have to insert this "var largestItem = d.FirstOrDefault(); " string in that row in field i.e. "research_area"

Comment: Let me try this @Grant

Comment: Your updated code looks fine but insertion doesn't working @Grant